# What are the risks of storing credentials in Electron renderer's localStorage?

Tags: javascript, security, electron

I have an Electron app, with one BrowserWindow. This BrowserWindow loads a local index.html (`file://` protocol) coded by me and bundled inside the Electron app, which serves my React single-page application. All JS files are obviously also bundled inside the Electron app.

I wish to store user credentials (such as access tokens, symmetrically-encrypted private keys) in the localStorage of the renderer process of the BrowserWindow. How safe it that?

Some additional info about my app:

- The React app loads some remote content (images, fonts, makes some AJAX calls, has some `<a>` links to the outside world), but doesn't load any remote javascript.
- I implemented the [official Electron security guidelines](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security), <strike>except number 3 "Enable Context Isolation for Remote Content".</strike> I also added number 3, after Rupp's comment.

Comment: Despite this is an interesting question, I think this is opinion-based, hence it may be considered off topic.

Comment: Due to isolated browser instances inside electron, will be a lot safer than doing it in a standard web app

Comment: Why in localStorage? As you are not using Context Isolation and can then create a JavaScript object to communicate with main, I'd go that route, you can make things harder for the hackers. localStorage may be slightly more vulnerable for XSS because hackers know it is there, while if you use a custom approach and call it from Javascript, it would require a little more reverse-engineering. Also consider what attack vectors are you exposed to, mind that downloading an electron app and enabling devTools on all browsers is a trivial operation.

Comment: @rupps good point, I ended up adding context isolation. "it would require a little more reverse-engineering" > the code is actually open-source. "Why in localStorage?" > because it's the simplest for me to code, but just wanted to make sure to which attack vectors it's exposed too. As said in the post, the React app loads remote assets(fonts/images) and makes ajax calls, that's all.